# one consumer for many queues

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

In my system, there are many users who write the blogs. I need to subscribe to different users. There is no centralized system(it's a swing application).

I am using JMS.

The user may follow one user, two users or 100 users.

```
m_destination1 = m_session.createQueue("USER.DEVID");
m_consumer1 = m_session.createConsumer(m_destination1);

m_destination2 = m_session.createQueue("USER.HARRY");
m_consumer2 = m_session.createConsumer(m_destination2);
```

Is there any generic way to write the above lines of code for unknown no. of users ? Like one consumer can receive message from many users.

Here wildcard will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing you can use is `Mirrored Queue` feature of activeMQ,
you can read the documentation here

- http://activemq.apache.org/mirrored-queues.html

What mirrored queue basically does is,it forwards all the messages sent on queue to a similar named topic, this topic can then be subscribed by multiple consumers.

If you use mirrored queue, you will need your consumers to subscribe to different topics.

Your design cries out for publish-subscribe(topic) domain rather than a point-to-point architecture(i.e queue).As you already would be having an architecture which generates a queue for different people writing blogs,change to that system wont be required but your requirement will be catered.

I addition to this,if 2 consumers listen on a queue then they will pick up messages parallely from queue i.e If there are 2 messages on queue then both consumers will process 1 message independently,I don't think that's what you want.

Hope this helps!
Good luck!

Comment: Got what you were looking for?

Comment: How does a mirrored queue help the OP achieve his/her goal of not having to explicitly specify the different users?

Comment: Different users will have to be created without doubt,but the question is asking for how can 2 users listen on one queue,and as it is a blog all users need to have a copy of that,which will not be possible with queue based approach,Mirrored queue internally uses topics by use of which this can be possible,and as we are using queue as an interface the existing architecture that OP has will not need to be changed and the requirement can be fulfilled

Comment: The OP asks "Is there any generic way to write the above lines of code for unknown no. of users?", which seems like a requirement that mirrored queues couldn't support (though topics could).  I think you're right that queues are an inappropriate approach, I just don't think that mirrored queues are any better given the OP's stated requirements (including the one I just quoted) so I'm not sure why you're advocating them instead of just telling the OP to use topics.

Answer (score 1):

@Vihar's answer is right that you should be using the publish-subscribe paradigm by using a topic, to allow multiple consumers to both be notified of new blog posts.  It sounds like your primary pain point is that you've got one destination per author and users that want to consume messages have to subscribe to each of them individually.

Instead, have all new-post messages published into a single topic (let's call it NewPostNotificationTopic).  Clients can then subscribe to all messages but immediately check them against the list of authors they care about and immediately stop processing any notification for an author they're not following.  (This puts the filtering into the message handler rather than into the ActiveMQ network.)  This does mean that each message will be passed to each client, but as long as the messages are small and your network is fast and your users are usually connected to the network, this might be a workable solution.  But if you can't afford the network bandwidth of sending all messages to all clients, or if your consumers will be offline for long periods of time and you can't afford to hold a copy of **all** messages till they come back online, this may not work for you.

Alternatively, publish all messages into that same topic, but set the author's ID as a header on the message and use message selectors to tell ActiveMQ to only deliver messages matching a given author ID.  This will be more efficient, but you're back to needing to explicitly tell ActiveMQ which authors you care about, either with a single subscription with a selector that contains ORs or with one subscription per author.  The latter is cleaner but gets you back to your problem of one subscription per author per reader; the former results in only one subscription but it has to be updated each time you add/remove an author for a reader, and you'll need to make sure you handle the race conditions inherent in removing the subscription and adding another one.  I'd go with the first solution I proposed (doing the filtering in the message handler instead of in the ActiveMQ subscriptions) if the performance concerns I raised there aren't a problem; otherwise I'd probably go with one subscription per author per reader, rather than having a single subscription with an ORed selector and needing to redo the subscription each time something changed.